# pg_restore: "-n" option is not importing large objects

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I am trying to import a database "demodb" from a dump using -n option. The intention is to import only specific schema called "demoschema". I create demodb as blank db before running pg_Restore. And I run the below command to restore:

```
pg_restore -d demodb -n demoschema dumpfile
```

Now the problem is pg_largeobject table is empty after restore.
If I remove option "-n demoschema" pg_largeobject will be restored too.

How do I use the option "-n" and also make sure catalogue tables like pg_largeobject are restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Either restore everything and drop what you don't need, or create a dump with `pg_dump -n demoschema --blobs` that contains exactly the data you need.

Comment: As per the document for --blobs option:

Include large objects in the dump. This is the default behavior except when --schema, --table, or --schema-only is specified.

Comment: Right. Since you specify `--schema` (= `-n`), you have to use `--blobs` explicitly.